# Android studio emulater

Tags: android, android-emulator

I hope all of you are doing great.
I am trying to add an android emulator in android studio. I added pixel 3 xl with 6GB of ram 4 GB of storage and android 10 with google Apis, but it crashes every time. I just see a frame and nothing else. It will be highly appreciated if you can help.
Looking forward to your help.

Comment: Does your computer CPU support virtualization? What are the specs of your machine? Did you tried with a different emulator?

Comment: Genymotion runs ok on my machine, it's just that it does not show frames of mobiles and no notch. Do you know any emulator that shows notch?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Genymotion` there is a free version here

`https://www.genymotion.com/fun-zone/`

and then you can add `Google APIs` manually.

If you have to use Android Studio Emulators make sure you downloaded `patcher` and `emulator` from SDK Manager.

Comment: How can i add device frames in genymotion?

Comment: Not sure, if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Android Studio 4.1? If so, try to update to the latest system images of the SDK.